# Curl Post JSON format to ActiveStorage in Rails with image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rails-activestorage

How can I post via curl to upload a file (image in this case) to active storage? The docs don't say exactly how to do it with curl, or with JS (e.g. Axios)

Something like this works (if I turn off the authenticity token (`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`)):

```
 curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d '{"image": {"user_id":"1"}}' http://localhost:3000/images.json
```

That will post as expected like a normal curl JSON request.

Encoding the file in base64 like this looks promising:

```
(echo -n '{"image": {"user_id":"1", "picture":"'; base64 /Users/cj/Desktop/DesktopArchive/5vvyo4u8y8wz.jpg; echo '"}}') | curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d @-  http://localhost:3000/images.json
```

Although I get a `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` on the upload. I am suspecting the base64 is not the correct signature. What should I use to encode the image to be uploaded to active storage?

Edit:

Not doing it via JSON, but by form works:

```
 curl \
   -F "image[user_id]=1" \
   -F "image[picture]=@/Users/cj/Desktop/DesktopArchive/5vvyo4u8y8wz.jpg" \
   http://localhost:3000/images
```

But still, how do you do it via a json call such that it can be done via Axios or something?

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: Not really. You have to do the form upload.

Comment: This cannot be done as far as I can tell

Comment: show your model. did you use has_many_attached in image model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my example is not same your image model.
but you can change you code after show my example code
https://github.com/x1wins/tutorial-rails-rest-api/blob/master/README.md#active-storage

> model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

> controller

```
  # posts_controller
  # POST /posts
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.files.attach(params[:post][:files]) if params.dig(:post, :files).present?

    set_category @post.category_id

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: api_v1_post_url(@post)
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  def update
    @post.files.attach(params[:post][:files]) if params.dig(:post, :files).present?
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/:id/attached/:id
  def destroy_attached
    attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:attached_id])
    attachment.purge # or use purge_later
  end
```

> curl

```
curl -F "post[body]=string123" \
        -F "post[category_id]=1" \
        -F "post[files][]=@/Users/rhee/Desktop/item/log/47310817701116.csv" \
        -F "post[files][]=@/Users/rhee/Desktop/item/log/47310817701116.csv" \
        -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts
```